# from curl to HTTPS request

Tags: javascript, curl, https, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem to transform this cURL:
`curl -F email=myname@example.com -F file=@file.txt https://srv-file6.gofile.io/uploadFile`   (srv-file6.gofile.io is an example in reality is something like srv-store6.gofile.io , saw from request itself)

into an HTTPS request on node.js.

```js
var xmlhttprequest = require ("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new xmlhttprequest();

xhr.open('POST','https://srv-store6.gofile.io/uploadFile',false,null,null);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
xhr.send('email=test@test.com&file=C:\\Users\\marco\\Pictures\\programming\\Cattura.png');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
}
```

I've tried using xmlhttprequest but doesn't work, I don't get any error message as responce but it dont upload the file.

Thats the site i took the api cURL from : https://gofile.io/api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send the file, first you need to read it in side your code. You can read the file and then send. Otherwise, you can use the below example which uses `fs` library to read the file and then `node-fetch` library to send the file.

First, install the `node-fetch` library:

```
npm i node-fetch
```

Then, try the below example:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var FormData = require('form-data');
let fs = require('fs');
let file = fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/marco/Pictures/programming/Cattura.png');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file );
formData.append('email', 'test@test.com' );

// @ts-ignore
fetch('https://srv-store6.gofile.io/uploadFile', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
})
.then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
}).then(function(json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow the instruction reported here https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/uploading-files-to-web-server-using-ajax-xhr/

Is it a server side operation or is it used by a front end page? Please post your front page also.

You are sending a string not a file data.

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append(‘myFile’, files[0], files[0].name);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open(‘POST’, ‘/upload’, true);

xhr.onload = function () {

if (xhr.status === 200) {

alert(‘File successfully uploaded’)

} else {

alert(‘File upload failed!’);

}

};

xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: i'm trying to call a server side operation with the call if you go to the link i posted there are the api documentation but im not getting how to perform this post request because it's explained only curl part